# Java - How to write a regex that includes disjunction of variables of a given set

Tags: java, regex, dictionary, set, information-retrieval

I need to retrieve the numbers followed by some specific units such as 10 m, 5 km... from given web pages. Those specific units are keys of a `map<String, Integer>`. `keySet()` returns a comma separated list, like `["m", "km"...]`. Is there a smart way to get the set as disjunction of the variables, like `["m"|"km"|...]` so that I could use it in a regex such as:

```
"(\\d+)"+ " " +"myMap.keySet()......"
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. Can you give some same input and output ?

Comment: Do you also want to include units in your match or just numbers that are followed by those units?

Answer (score 1):

join the set with pipes:
`"(\\d+)\\s*(" + StringUtils.join(myMap.keySet(), "|") + ")"`

Comment: Result of `keySet()` invoked on Map instance is Set, and Sets doesn't have `join` method in Java.

Comment: @Pshemo: Sorry, I didn't realize that. I have updated the solution to use StringUtils. Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
myMap.keySet().toString().replaceAll(",\\s*", "|").replaceAll("^\\[|\\]$", "")
//                       ^                         ^
//                       |                         +remove [ at start and ] at end
//                       +replace `,` and spaces after it with |
```

instead

```
myMap.keySet()
```

Your code can look like this

```
String data = "1km is equal 1000 m, and 1  m is equal 100cm. 1 mango shouldnt be found";

Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("m", 1);
map.put("km", 2);
map.put("cm", 3);

String regex = "\\d+\\s*("
        + map.keySet().toString()       //will create "[cm, m, km]"
            .replaceAll(",\\s*", "|")   //will change it to "[cm|m|km]"
            .replaceAll("^\\[|\\]$", "")//will change it to "cm|m|km"
        + ")\\b";                       
    // I added \\b - word boundary - to prevent matching `m` if it is at
    // start of some word like in 1 mango where it normally would match
    // (1 m)ango

Pattern p=Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m=p.matcher(data);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
String p = "\\d+ (?:";
for (String key : yourMap.keySet())
   p += key + "|";
p = p.substring(0, p.length() - 1) + ")";
```